Upload an attachment to Azure DevOps via HTTP POST requestU
Im using n8n to create an integration Movidesk/AzureDevOps.
Im trying to get the attachments people put in the Movidesk to an AzureDevOps workitem, but cant figure out how to upload the attachment in the first place. The part of linkink it to a workitem I manage to succeded.
Since im using, i cant download anything in my local computer, so what i have to work with in this situation is just:
"attachments":[ 
        { 
          "fileName":"minhaImagem.png",
          "path":"7BDEA1B62A8641FF86982D0CF9F3DEC0",
          "createdBy":{ 
            "id":"CodRefDeQuemEnviouOArquivo",
            "personType":1,
            "profileType":1,
            "businessName":"Nome de quem enviou o arquivo",
            "email":"email@pessoa.com",
            "phone":"(47) 99999-9999"
          },
          "createdDate":"2017-05-29T14:19:50.0129141"
        }
      ],

But i dont know how to use the "path" variable.
For
I used this post api call:

POST https://dev.azure.com/%7BmyOrg%7D/%7BmyProject%7D/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName=test.xlsx&api-version=7.1-preview.3

It returns me an id and a url as it should, but when i open it it has no content.
I assumed it was a problem with the body of the API.Its missing something the content itself of the file, but i didnt figured it out how to use it with only the fileName and the path
in the work item, it stays like this. If i try downloading it, the file returns me an error that the file is corrupted


To upload an attachment to Azure DevOps and link the attachment to a work item via the REST API request, please follow the following steps:

Convert file content to binary data. The sample PowerShell script:

$fileName = "123.png" # replace with your file name and file name extension
$filePath = "C:\Users\xxxx\Pictures\Screenshots\"+$fileName # replace with your file path
$fileContent = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($filePath)


Upload the binary file to Azure DevOps as attachment.

POST https://dev.azure.com/xxxxx/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName=fileName.png&api-version=7.2-preview.4

You will get an id and a url as return. We will use the url from the response.
Example response:
{
  "id": "a5cedde4-2dd5-4fcf-befe-fd0977dd3433",
  "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxxx/_apis/wit/attachments/a5cedde4-2dd5-4fcf-befe-fd0977dd3433?fileName=fileName.png"
}


Add an attachment to the workitem.

PATCH https://dev.azure.com/xxxxx/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=7.2-preview.3

[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
      "rel": "AttachedFile",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxxx/_apis/wit/attachments/a5cedde4-2dd5-4fcf-befe-fd0977dd3433?fileName=fileName.png",
      "attributes": {
        "comment": "Attachment uploaded"
      }
    }
  }
]

Here is the full sample PowerShell script:
$organization = ""
$project = ""
$personalAccessToken=""

$fileName = "123.png" # replace with your file name and file name extension
$filePath = "C:\Users\xxxx\Pictures\Screenshots\"+$fileName # replace with your file path
$workItemId = "583"  # Replace with your work item ID

# Convert file content to binary data
$fileContent = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($filePath)

# Upload the file to Azure DevOps
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName=$fileName&api-version=7.2-preview.4"  
$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$personalAccessToken"))
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $fileContent -ContentType  "application/octet-stream"
$attachmentUrl = $response.url

# Link the attachment to the work item
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/wit/workitems/$($workItemId)?api-version=7.2-preview.3"
$body = @"
[
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/relations/-",
        "value": {
            "rel": "AttachedFile",
            "url": "$attachmentUrl",
            "attributes": {
                "comment": "Attachment uploaded via PowerShell script"
            }
        }
    }
]
"@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Patch -Headers $headers -Body $body -ContentType "application/json-patch+json"


Test result:

I can download these files and read them successfully.

I get the whole process, myy problem is that i dont have the actual file downloaded in my computer. I have to work with it in the endpoint(n8n) by getting the file through an API GET call from movidesk using this “path” variable, which I can't do. I believe that solving this API issue to download the file would solve it, since the rest you explained very well.

Hi @LosinChances, I found this question in n8n community for your reference.  It mentions that you can download attachment with the HTTP Request Node. You just have to make sure to set “Response Format” to “File”.
